# Compare date and time in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, filter

I'm writing a mongo query to show records based on the current time. However, the query returns 0 records when I try to query against date and time. Below is the query:

```
let now =  momenttz.tz(moment(),tz).toDate();
 tmpl.listSelectorFilter('scheduledVisits', {
    $gte: now,
    $lte: moment.utc(today, 'MM/DD/YYYY').endOf('week').toDate()
  });
```

Note: If I set the time to zero hours, it works.

How do I change this query in order to make it work? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Does the data you're querying against have timestamps or a dateTime object to compare? Essentially you aren't comparing the records to any time, so there is no way for mongo to know what to filter by.

I would suggest you do something like a find instead and compare to dates within the record with the appropriate date field:

example:

```
db.collection.find({
{ $and: [ { data.date: { $gte: now } }, { data.date: { $lte: endOfWeek } } ] }
})
```

also keep in mind that in mongo land you can't use functions like you would do with moment, hence why I put "endOfWeek" which would be a variable you set similar to now:

```
let now =  momenttz.tz(moment(),tz).toDate();
let endOfWeek = moment.utc(today, 'MM/DD/YYYY').endOf('week').toDate()
```